# Can I add a disabledIcon to a Flex Menu for use in PopUpButton

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I am using the Flex PopUpButton & data binding a Menu object to the popup. I successfully added an `icon` to a menu item; however, it does not look like Menu supports the `disabledIcon` property common in many other elements for use when `enabled: false` for that menu item.

Is it possible to extend the Flex Menu class to use `disabledIcon`? Should I use a different type of data binding class?

```
// create the array collection of menu items
var menuItems:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

var addWidget:Object = new Object();        
addWidget = ({label: "Add",
              id: ADD_WIDGET_ID,
              icon: addIcon,
              disabledIcon: addDisabledIcon,
              enabled: false});
menuItems.addItem(addWidget);

var myMenu:Menu = new Menu();
myMenu.dataProvider = menuItems;

productActionsButton.popUp = myMenu;
```

The above code will produce a disabled `Add` menu item where the menu item icon is `addIcon` instead of the desired `addDisabledIcon` because Mx:Menu does not currently support `disabledIcon`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would extend mx.controls.menuClasses.MenuItemRenderer and override the updateDisplayList method to change which icon is shown based on the enabled property.  Hope that helps.